# 2 monitors on GPU, 1 monitor on integrated graphics

Tags: cinnamon, display, gpu

I am on linux mint 17.1 cinnamon. Here is my xorg.conf: http://pastebin.com/6xCncZJ5

I can move my mouse around on the 3 monitors but can not drag the windows over the borders. Cinnamon is running in fallback mode.

Edit: I set Xinerama to "on". Now my gpu monitors work normally but the mobo monitor only shows my cursor moving, on a black background.

Comment: Putting "Edit" in a question is superfluous, we can all see the edit history. It would be much more helpful if there was an actual question, i.e. a sentence with question mark in your post.

Comment: I have the same issue. When using two GPUs, Cinammon fails to Fallback mode and won't start up in normal mode. Is it possible to get Cinnamon to support two GPUs?